# Uploaded images stripped of EXIF data

Tags: assets, upload

I've got a clean install of Craft with just some initial configuration of entry types, categories, assets, etc.

Any image I upload (either directly into assets or via an image field) has almost all of its EXIF metadata stripped out. Most of the removed info I don't care about, but it's essential that the embedded copyright, geolocation and keyword information is retained.

I assume this has something to do with the configuration of ImageMagick/GD (whichever Craft uses by default). Is there a way I can create a configuration that specifies which EXIF fields to preserve in the uploaded image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently the images are being cleansed on upload, which means that they are being re-saved to make sure that no malicious code is injected in them.

Unfortunately, this means that EXIF data gets stripped out along the way, but since Craft already uses [PEL](https://github.com/lsolesen/pel), it should be possible to tweak Craft a bit so that the EXIF metadata is preserved during this operation. We'll look into that and, hopefully, this will make it to a release pretty soon.

Comment: Thanks, and good to hear it shouldn't be hard to fix. Currently this is a dealbreaker for me using Craft on a few sites.

Comment: @EvanWarner, Andris: I'm not exactly sure what you both are talking about, as I have a lot of EXIF metadata, that I can access from uploaded assets with my plugin [Asset Metadata](https://github.com/carlcs/craft-assetmetadata) (uses the library [getID3](http://getid3.sourceforge.net)). Why does this work for me?

Comment: @carlcs: Not sure why it works for you but I'd love to find out. [Here's a diff](https://gist.github.com/evanwarner/8e138896a52cf47d9e0e) of my image EXIF pre- and post-upload.

Comment: @carlcs, are these assets uploaded via Craft or uploaded outside of Craft and indexed thereafter?

Comment: Uploaded from the CP. ImageMagick is installed, if that matters.

Answer (score 2):

For Craft 3 the setting 'preserveExifData' in config/general.php should be [set to true](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-config-generalconfig.html#public-properties)